# How can I add content of different rows of my jTable in a variable?

Tags: java, loops, swing, for-loop, jtable

sorry if my question looks stupid but I'm not really good at For loops.
My window looks like this.

[jFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaevT.png)

When I click on "valider", I want to add every rows in the Prix column to a variable Total.
Here is my loop:

```
float total = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < jTable4.getRowCount(); i++)
 total =+ (float) jTable4.getValueAt( i, 2);
```

When I check what's in my Total variable, it just gives me the content of the last row.

Could you guys help me with this loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is **you have used an invalid assignment Operator . =+ should be change as += to get your expected answer .**

```
float total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < jTable4.getRowCount(); i++) {  // Loop through the rows
       
        total += (float) jTable4.getValueAt(i, 2);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't think it was something so stupid lmao.

Comment: @Jay3001 Glad to be of help.Please up vote the answer if you found it useful.